# Opengl ES sliding texture animation

Tags: opengl-es

I d like to animate a texture on a vertex from left to right. How can i do this?

my old code is:

```
        float texCoords[] = { 
            iTextcoord, 0.0f, 
            iTextcoord, 1.0f, 
            iTextcoord+1.0f, 0.0f, 
            iTextcoord+1.0f, 1.0f, 
        };
        this.setTextureCoords(texCoords);
```

but its isnt the best:(

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE_MATRIX)`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glMatrixMode.xml) and [`glTranslatef()`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/glTranslate.xml).